# Library to aid with creating sites that users register for

Tags: php

I am trying to create a website that users have to register for, and this gives them access to all the site features. Potentially, maybe i want users to pay a yearly subscription fee.

Is there a library to handle this for me? This should include, keeping track of user cookie and logged in status, keeping track of expiry date, verifying email addresses, banned users... etc.
I mainly use PHP and MySQL but am open to using something else if there is this really good library out there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Zend library can give you a lot of those chunks of code with a little setup. That would be my best recommendation but if you want something that is a little more setup from the get go I would recommend using a Drupal install to accomplish most of this functionality.

Drupal has many modules that can be setup and configured to handle most of this. Including the subscriptions, though you will need to setup a payment gateway in order to process them. I know Authorize.net offers a subscription service, but my bet is the setup will work with Paypal or Google Checkout as well.

Hope that helps give you some direction to solve your problem. :)